# Can exception masking be completely prevented with try-with-resources statement

Tags: java, exception, try-with-resources

I'm aware that try-with-resources statement was introduced to cure (or) prevent exception masking.

Consider the following code:

```
class TestExceptionSuppressing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            testMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            for (Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()) {
                System.err.println("Suppressed Exceptions List: " + t);
            }
        }
    }

    static void testMethod() {
        try (InnerClass inner = new InnerClass()) {
            throw new IOException("Exception thrown within try block");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Exception thrown within catch block.Hence exception thrown within try block will be lost (or) masked");
        }
    }

    static class InnerClass implements AutoCloseable {

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception("Exception thrown in close method will be tacked on to existing exceptions");
        }
    }
}
```

Output: *Exception thrown within catch block.Hence exception thrown within try block will be lost (or) masked*

Apparently, exception thrown in catch block of testMethod() has masked both the io exception thrown in try block and also the exception suppressed and added to this io exception(thrown in close method )

This code example might prove that try-with-resources may not completely prevent exception masking.

I'm aware things are mixed up in here and might be confused but is a possible case to happen. **My question is, is there a way to prevent this scenario i.e. exception masking to still happen even when using try-with-resources statement?**

Comment: This is a change that was introduced at the same time as try with resource, but a plain try/finally block with allow you to see suppressed exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep the original exception if you use [RuntimeException(String, Throwable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html#RuntimeException(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable))

> Constructs a new runtime exception with the specified detail message and cause.

```
throw new RuntimeException(
                "Exception thrown within catch block  won't be lost (or) masked", e);
```

If you want to add the suppressed try and resources exception, you need to use the [addSuppressed(Throwable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)) method, in your case:

```
RuntimeException runtimeException = new RuntimeException(
                    "Exception thrown within try block won't be lost (or) masked", e);
            runtimeException.addSuppressed(e.getSuppressed()[0]);
```

More info in [Suppressed Exceptions and Try With Resources](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/OCPJP-OCAJP-Java-7-Suppressed-Exceptions-Try-With-Resources)

> However, just because the CloseException is supressed in this scenario, it doesn't mean this suppressed exception has be ignored. To address this concept of suppressed exceptions, two new methods and a constructor have been added to the java.lang.Throwable class in Java 7.
>
> ```
> public final void addSuppressed(Throwable exception)
> ```

Comment: That works with practically all exceptions, too, not just with RuntimeException. You can later retrieve the wrapped exception with `getCause()`.

Comment: @Thilo you are generally right, but I saw (mostly customized) exception types that forget to add it option

Comment: @user7294900 -  Do you say that the exception thrown in the assocaited block of try-with-resourced statement will not be masked with this approach. Message you specified says about exception thrown in catch block will not be lost. I reckon it’s a typo error. Isn’t it? Also, can we specify checked exceptions also in this manner such that the original exception is not lost?

Comment: @sake add to my answer adding the exception thrown in the associated block of try-with-resourced statement

Comment: @user7294900 - I believe with this approach (i.e. providing the cause while constructing a throwable and adding suppressed expection to the constructed throwable in catch block), we may get the (otherwise) masked exception thrown in try-with-reosurces statement  as the cause for exception in catch block but as I mentioned in my question, exception masking can still happen with try-with-resources statement and cannot be completely prevented. Do you agree?

Comment: @sake I agree that exception handling should be more straight forward and without coding explicitly exceptions can be masked